# Should I emit microservice events with all the data required on the receiving end, or allow the services to fetch extra data from the database?

Tags: database-design, architecture, microservices, nestjs, google-cloud-pubsub

I have the following servers running on my cloud, where each worker performs various long running tasks and may update my PostgreSQL database:

```
- Main application server
- Service that collects changes and updates my search database
- Worker
- Worker
- Worker
```

When my `main server`, or either of my `workers` updates my database, my ORM middleware emits a Cloud Pub/Sub event that the data has changed. This allows my `search service` to then process the changes and update my search cluster in bulk batches.

The part I'm struggling with is simply where I should fetch the extra data required to process the events, while maintaining scalability and clean architecture.

**For example:**

I have accommodation properties that have their `availability` synced externally. Each `day` gets updated in my database and must reflect in the search index. The problem is that I also need the property's pricing model, and various other meta data to be updated in my search.
Should I:

**A)** Emit an event that a `day`'s availability has changed and in the `Search Service`, fetch the property and it's pricing from the database

**B)** Fetch the property and it's pricing from the database in the ORM middleware, and THEN emit the event, allow the `Search Service` to simply consume and update the search database

How generic should my PubSub events be, and how much data should be prepared before vs after the event has emitted?

Comment: I think you should calirfy a cople things before you get a good answer as a couple of things are not clear. For example: 1. accommodation properties that have their availability synced externally? What do you mean by synced externally? By some async process? From another micro-service? 2. Option A: Do you mean fetch property data from db and send it with the Event together with day's availability data? 3. In general who is publishing the Event and who is subscribing to it and what is the use case?Please try to edit the questions and give a little bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get on with this?  Here's my thinking for anyone in the same boat...

The key is to think about, and correctly balance, design time and runtime considerations - such as:

- Data volatility.
- Do consumers care about history.
- Runtime load. ​
- Ease of debugging and operational support.
- Ease of maintenance / making system changes.
- Financial cost.

If the data is highly volatile (changes frequently) then your approach A is better, because the consumer will always be getting the latest data - i.e. latency between when they got the notification and when they get the data doesn't matter.

Approach A also reduces both the load on the source systems and the middleware/integration: the source systems only need to publish the event, not do further work to build a bigger answer (approach B).  There's less data flowing through the middleware, which puts less load on it and may affect how much it costs to operate if you're on a *aaS platform.

Approach A allows you to make changes to the API's that return the data (the "GET" API) without having to change the API's & specs for the events.  This means you can run one simple and stable (doesn't change very often / at all) set of events, and multiple versions of the GET API, allowing consumers to migrate when they are ready (e.g. if your support model is to support the current version -X.2).

I would consider approach B in situations where:

- Consumers needed all the changes, not just the latest ones.
- The extra data to return was not massive, i.e. not going to degrade performance of the source systems or the middleware.  Where there was an impact to the source system you may want to investigate ways of reducing the burden - e.g. response caching, some sort of proxy, whatever.
- The schema of the full data payload was relatively stable.